# Margins on JPanel with MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, miglayout

I created an `OptionDialog` without any buttons and put a `JPanel` in it that uses `MigLayout` for its layout.  That `JPanel` has another `JPanel` inside of it.

Both of these panels seem to have a margin on the outside of it.  Maybe it is padding on the container.  Either way I would like a way to get rid of them.

How can I get rid of these margins?  In the picture they are the grey and the dark orange borders around the JPanels.

[image: JPanel]

Here is the panel code:

```
setBackground(new Color(239,209,59));
setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap 1"));
JLabel title = new JLabel("Enroll Today!", JLabel.CENTER);
Font f = title.getFont().deriveFont((float)36);
title.setFont(f);
add(title);
JPanel docsPanel = new JPanel();
docsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
docsPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap 1", "", "[grow,fill]"));
docsPanel.setBackground(new Color(255,235,115));
for (final Document d : docs){
    JButton doc = new JButton("* "+d.getName());
    doc.setFont(f.deriveFont((float)24));
    doc.setBorder(null);
    doc.setContentAreaFilled(false);
docsPanel.add(doc);
}
add(docsPanel);
```

Here is the OptionDialog code:

```
DocumentPanel panel = new DocumentPanel(controller.getDocuments());
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Enroll now!", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                             JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new Object[] {}, null);
```

Comment: Can you show some code.

Comment: I pasted in the code.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blindly,  try `"ins 0, wrap 1"` in the `MigLayout` constructor.

Comment: Excellent! that got rid of the Dark orange padding for the inner JPanel.  Do you have any idea for the OptionDialog that is containing the whole Panel?

Comment: I just pasted the code where I create the OptionDialog.  As you can see you don't add the panel to a MigLayout.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea :) , I just add the swing tag to your question, hope that someone else can help you.